# How to give padding to font?

Tags: html, css

I am using a downloaded font file for use on my website, however it is causing some issues in regards to layout / display.

Most fonts I have used display like this

[image: Most Fonts]

The font I am currently using displays like *this*:

[image: This font]

The difference is that the 1st font has space above (which is part of the actual text and not my css styling) while the second one has no space at all.

I can solve this issue by simply adding some extra padding to the containing element's top but this is not practical in the future event that I decide to replace the font (meaning I would have to go into every parent and remove the `padding-top`)

Is there any CSS styling methods I can use to add padding to my font so that it will always have a bit of space up top?

My Code:

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Anakin Mono";
    src: url("../fonts/opipik_anakinmono/anakinmono.ttf");
}
#demo {
    font-family: "Anakin Mono";
    padding: 14px 10px 10px 10px;   /* Have to add extra padding to top becuase of font in use */
    border: 1px solid black; /* A border helps illuminate whats happening with text alignment - vertically;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="demo">Some text on my website</p>
```

Comment: Add your related source code as well

Comment: Why do you have to go into every parent? Each parent containing the special font should be assigned a CSS class like ".font-fix-padding", in which you can add the padding. If you decide to change the font later, you can just change the padding assigned to that class.

Comment: add your related `HTML` and `CSS` codes.

Comment: @Felix Guo While that IS a good solution, it's avoiding the problem. I don't want to have to add padding - I want to somehow fix the source of the problem (the font)

Comment: @FlameStinger - if that's the case, you'll have to find a way to edit the font itself.  It cannot be done with css other than adding a class and appropriate padding which is what you've already stated you do not want to do.

Comment: @billynoah and Felix Guo What about placeholders? I cant give them a class? can I?

Comment: What about `line-height` ?

Comment: I'd swap out the font instead of worrying about this. The font you want to use looks unprofessional and is obviously not well made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any CSS styling methods I can use to add padding to my font so that it will always have a bit of space up top?

Unfortunately the answer to this question as you've outlined it is **no**, there are no CSS methods to target only a single font.

That said, you can simply assign your mono-spaced font by using a class and easily change the style globally as shown here:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata');
.monospace {
  font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="monospace">This element is monospaced font</div>
```

Any elements which you'd like to use your mono spaced font should be assigned the class `monospace`.  In the future, you can simply change the `font-family` rule and alter the padding and voila, you've accomplished your change with very little effort.

I realize you've made it clear in the comments that you'd rather take a different approach, but I feel this is the absolute best solution/workaround that will get you what you want with the least amount of effort.  At most, it will require you alter your markup to add the `monospace` class where needed, but this is probably a step in the right direction anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `line-height`. Change your CSS to this:

```
#demo {
    font-family: "Anakin Mono", sans-serif;
    line-height: 3;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

You can try different values of `line-height`. It accepts multiple of original line height. px or em.

Always remember not to use only ONE font in `font-family`. Use more than 1 font to provide fallback fonts, in case your font is not loaded yet / unable to load.

Also, it's not advised to use self-hosted TTF font unless the file size is small. Try using CDN-hosted web fonts (such as Google Fonts) for better performance.

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/okawrcuf/6/ (I used another font that is available in Google Fonts for demo purpose, as I don't have your font)

Comment: How small is "small"? Most of my fonts are `<` 200kb

Comment: everything you've said here is good advice, but I don't see how it solves his problem - which is that he wants an extra padding at the top *of only this one font* and not other fonts, should he choose to switch it up.

Comment: @billynoah he can create a CSS class for his font (a common way to do so), specifying the font family and line height. Some designers will adjust the character spacing in the same CSS class as well.

Comment: @FlameStinger 200kb is quite large already. For visitors with slow Internet connection, they might experience **FOUS**, Flash of Unstyled Content, which is undesirable. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) for more information about this common issue.